# How can I find the sum of even and odd values in array in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I guess there is another way by using for each loop but can I do it in a simple way

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter ten values in the array"
for((n=0;n<10;n++))
do
   read array[n];
done
even=0
odd=0

 for((i=0;i<10;i++))
 do
   if($((array[i]%2==0)))
   then
     $even=array[i]+$even
   else 
     $odd=array[i]+$odd
   fi
done

echo"Sum of Even number in the array is $even"
```

Comment: Don't put `$` before the variable when assigning to it.

Comment: You need to use `$((expression))` to evaluate an arithmetic expression.

Comment: In $even=array[i]+$even ?

Answer (score 3):

1. When assigning to a variable, you don't put `$` before the destination variable. So it should be `even=`, not `$even=`.
2. Use `$((...))` to evaluate an expression.
3. In a conditional context, you can just use `((...))`. `$((...))` inserts the result of the expression into the command line, it doesn't test whether it's successful.

```
for ((i=0;i<10;i++))
do
    if ((array[i]%2==0))
    then
        even=$((array[i]+even))
    else 
        odd=$((array[i]+odd))
    fi
done
```

Comment: `for n;do ((a[n%2]+=n))||:;done;printf 'Even sum: %d\nOdd sum: %d\n' "${a[@]}"`

Comment: @Barmar: `((even+=array[i]))` would be more idiomatic, IMO.

Comment: @user1934428 There are lots of idiomatic ways to write this, but it seems more instructive to just fix the OP's errors rather than rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Alternately, 2 loops:

```sh
for ((i=0; i<10; i += 2)); do ((even += array[i])); done
for ((i=1; i<10; i += 2)); do ((odd  += array[i])); done
# ......^........^^^^^^
```

Comment: I think OP means odd-valued elements rather than elements with  odd indices.

Comment: Ah indeed. I'll leave this here anyway, perhaps I'll collect some downvotes...